# post a comment on facebook wall after submitting a button on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post a comment on users facebook wall after submitting a button on my website?

On my web page users can review certain products and after they review them the press on ‘submit review’ button. I want to make the review report to be published on the user’s facebook feed.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

For a normal post, you can use the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) – this does not require that the user connect to your app first.

If you want to post via API in the background, then you have to have the user login to your app first.

If you do not want a normal post, then look into Open Graph actions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/